# How to specify AzureWebJobsStorage in latest azure webjob 3.03

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I updated my old azure webjob code to package to 3.03 and then it is just not working.

I managed to fix all compile-time errors, but when running locally, it throws this error:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Indexers.FunctionIndexingException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Error indexing method 'MvQueueProcessorV2.ProcessMVRequest'
  Source=Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.RecoverableException.TryRecover(ILogger logger) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Exceptions\RecoverableException.cs:line 81
   at FE.Toolkit.MvPaaS.WebJob.Program.<Main>(String[] args)

Inner Exception 1:
InvalidOperationException: Storage account 'Storage' is not configured.
```

For me, this seems to indicate that it can't find setting **AzureWebJobsStorage**? However, it sleeps nicely in the app.config file. So I assumed that I should put my connection string to appsettings.json, so this is what I did in my appsettings.json:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "xxx",
    "Storage": "yyy"
  }
}
```

However, it gives me the same error. So how do I set storage for webjob 3.0?

This is my code in program.cs

```
var builder = new HostBuilder()
              .UseEnvironment("Development")
              .ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
               {
                 b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices()
                   .AddAzureStorage()
                   .AddTimers()
                   .AddFiles()
                   .AddDashboardLogging();
                   })
                  .ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
                 {
                   b.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
                   b.AddConsole();
                  })
                   .ConfigureServices(services =>
                  {
                        services.AddSingleton<INameResolver, ConfigNameResolver>();
                  })
               .UseConsoleLifetime();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add this line of code in your program.cs:

```
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) => {
                    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
                })
```

I have tested at my side, and works fine.

code in Program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace WebJob1template
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            var builder = new HostBuilder()
                .UseEnvironment("Development")
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) => {
                    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
                })
                .ConfigureWebJobs(
                b =>
                {
                    b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices()
                    .AddAzureStorage()
                    .AddTimers()
                    .AddFiles();
                    //.AddDashboardLogging();
                })
                .ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
                {
                    b.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
                    b.AddConsole();
                })
                .UseConsoleLifetime();


            var host = builder.Build();

            using (host)
            {
                host.Run();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

appsettings.json(note that set it's property "Copy to Output Directory" as Copy always):

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "xxxx",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "xxxx"
  }
}
```

Function.cs:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace WebJob1template
{
    public class Functions
    {        
        public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("queue")] string message, ILogger log)
        {
            //log.WriteLine(message);
            log.LogInformation(message);
        }
    }
}
```

The test result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and [here is my solution](https://github.com/hemantshelar/dotnetcore-webjobs).

Below are the Azure assemblies that I am referring to

[image]

With above setup, there is no need to invoke `c.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", ... )` if name of config file is 'appSettings.json'

By default, framework will look for the file named '`appsettings.json`'

However, if name of file is something else the we need to tell `HostBuilder` what is name of our config file.

```
HostBuilder builder = new HostBuilder();

//Below piece of code is not required if name of json file is 'appsettings.json'
builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(c =>
{
   c.AddJsonFile("Myappsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

});
```

Simple and important step **that cause problem** while debugging on my local machine was '`Copy to Output Directory`'property of my '`appsettings.json`' file.  @Ivan Yang has already mentioned this in his answer.

[image]

[Here](https://github.com/hemantshelar/dotnetcore-webjobs) is the git hub link of the source code.

Note: I have followed [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started) to implement the code base.